# What to use instead of componentWillReceiveProps when resetting internal state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component that needs to reset an error in state everytime a new prop is changed. My current solution looks like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.teamPoints !== this.props.teamPoints && nextProps.teamPoints) {
      if (this.state.formError) {
        this.setState({ formError: '' });
      }
    }
  }
```

It just resets the `formError` when the prop is changed (the prop comes from redux). I've searched and searched for a better solution to this, but have yet to find one better than this (as componentDidUpdate causes the app to re-render).

What is a better alternative?

Comment: [Swap `componentWillReceiveProps` to `componentDidUpdate` instead](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops). The prop change will cause your component to re-render regardless, so it's no problem setting your state inside an if statement here. `componentDidUpdate` will cause an additional re-render, but it's not visible to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the React [blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key):

> When a key changes, React will create a new component instance rather than update the current one.

So if your component is simple and `formError` is the only part of `state`, supply your component with a `key` prop. Then when you want to reset `formError`, change the `key` prop. This will cause a new instance of the component to be created.